# Incorrect displaying of russian characters in Python / Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, lxml

I am trying to parse a russian website using lxml. However ,I got an issue with displaying russian characters, that i am unable to overcome myself.

Let's take this html piece for example:

```
<a href="http://www.2do2go.ru/msk/events/41600/kvest-v-realnosti-karty-dengi-dva-stola" class="medium-events-list_link">Квест в реальности «Карты, деньги, два стола»</a>
```

I am using this piece to parse it:

```
title = root.xpath('//*[@id="event-id-41600"]/div[3]/div[2]/a/text()')[0].encode('utf-8').strip()
```

and this is what i get:

```
├É┬Ü├É┬▓├É┬Á├Ĺ┬ü├Ĺ┬é ├É┬▓ ├Ĺ┬Ç├É┬Á├É┬░├É┬╗├Ĺ┬î├É┬Ż├É┬ż├Ĺ┬ü├Ĺ┬é├É┬Ş ├é┬ź├É┬Ü├É┬░├Ĺ┬Ç├Ĺ┬é├Ĺ┬ő, ├É┬┤├É┬Á├É┬Ż├Ĺ┬î├É┬│├É┬Ş, ├É┬┤├É┬▓├É┬░ ├Ĺ┬ü├Ĺ┬é├É┬ż├É┬╗├É┬░├é┬╗
```

In database however instead of cyrillic i see this:

```
ÐÐ²ÐµÑÑ Ð² ÑÐµÐ°Ð»ÑÐ½Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸ Â«ÐÐ°ÑÑÑ, Ð´ÐµÐ½ÑÐ³Ð¸, Ð´Ð²Ð° ÑÑÐ¾Ð»Ð°Â»
```

Oh and btw for reference:

this piece:

```
title = item.xpath('div[3]/div[2]/a')[0]
print etree.tostring(title)
```

returns me this :

```
<a href="http://www.2do2go.ru/msk/events/41600/kvest-v-realnosti-karty-dengi-dva-stola" class="medium-events-list_link">&#208;&#154;&#208;&#178;&#208;&#181;&#209;&#129;&#209;&#130; &#208;&#178; &#209;&#128;&#208;&#181;&#208;&#176;&#208;&#187;&#209;&#140;&#208;&#189;&#208;&#190;&#209;&#129;&#209;&#130;&#208;&#184; &#194;&#171;&#208;&#154;&#208;&#176;&#209;&#128;&#209;&#130;&#209;&#139;, &#208;&#180;&#208;&#181;&#208;&#189;&#209;&#140;&#208;&#179;&#208;&#184;, &#208;&#180;&#208;&#178;&#208;&#176; &#209;&#129;&#209;&#130;&#208;&#190;&#208;&#187;&#208;&#176;&#194;&#187;</a>
```

Not sure if it is database related of something to do with python encoding. Any help appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: i am using MySQL and Django ORM

Django settings:

```
DATABASE_OPTIONS = {
  "charset": "utf8_general_ci",
  "init_command": "SET storage_engine=INNODB"
}
```

Webpage :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#" class="">
    <head>
        <title>Интересные события в Москве в январе  - феврале 2016</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: I am using python 2.7.3

Comment: Try to remove the `encode` part: `root.xpath('//*[@id="event-id-41600"]/div[3]/div[2]/a/text()')[0].strip()` may be this will help.

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-9: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I just realized that it ends up encoded as "latin-1" in my database...not sure why...

Comment: Try adding set encoding to utf-8 command (don't remember mysql syntax here) in `init_command` and see if it helps. If it is, then you'll have to run it manually on your DB directly one time, and then remove from `init_command`.

Comment: Oh i got this. Actually all i needed to change is : encode('utf-8') to encode('latin-1')....

Comment: If you plan to work with cyrillic and Django it's best to use utf-8. See notes on how to properly set utf-8 and MySQL here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#mysql-notes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cyrillic code page does not exist/not setted up on your server. So you can`t view russian characters in terminal even in UTF-8. But python stil work with unicode properly.

By this command:

```
title = root.xpath('//*[@id="event-id-41600"]/div[3]/div[2]/a/text()')[0].encode('utf-8').strip()
```

you get **unicode string** and encode it to **bytes** (str in python2). And save bytes in database.

When you load string from database python uses default code page (probably Latin-1) and you get this:

```
ÐÐ²ÐµÑÑ Ð² ÑÐµÐ°Ð»ÑÐ½Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸ Â«ÐÐ°ÑÑÑ, Ð´ÐµÐ½ÑÐ³Ð¸, Ð´Ð²Ð° ÑÑÐ¾Ð»Ð°Â»
```

So, you should store unicode string in database (don't use encode)

```
title = root.xpath('//*[@id="event-id-41600"]/div[3]/div[2]/a/text()')[0].strip()
```

P.S. I don't understand how encode('Latin-1') helps (from comments), but problem is solved :)

Comment: yeah but the thing is i need to have those records in database in cyrillic as in Квест в реальности Карты, деньги, два стола. How can i do this? I know that Django assumes that all databases use UTF-8 encoding. So i guess i need to change the charset setting to latin-1? I'll try that.

Comment: you shouldn't use encode when parse. Just save string in database, because it already in unicode.

Comment: yeah i understand that :) but without it i end up having ÐÐ²ÐµÑÑ Ð² ÑÐµÐ°Ð»ÑÐ½Ð¾ÑÑÐ¸ Â«ÐÐ°ÑÑÑ, Ð´ÐµÐ½ÑÐ³Ð¸, Ð´Ð²Ð° ÑÑÐ¾Ð»Ð°Â» as a record. I actually had to use .encode('latin-1') to have cyrillic. But thanks for help :)